# Installing ubuntu 15.04 on new SSD drive

Tags: 15.04, hard-drive, ssd

I got a new SSD drive for my Hp Elitebook 2530p. I want to install Ubuntu on that disk and NOT copy anything from old hard drive. What should I consider when doing this? I've seen lots of links showing how to copy old system, but I don't need to do this, so is there anything special I need to know before installing new drive?

Comment: I found this post helpful for *after* you install your ssd: https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/07/5-crucial-optimizations-for-ssd-usage-in-ubuntu-linux/. Also, I have installed Ubuntu on ssds in two separate computers without issue just by following the normal install process

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special to it.

When installing, if the old drives are still connected to the computer, you should select "something else" as the installation method instead of the other options to ensure that Ubuntu is installed on the correct drive. Then you will have to configure the partitions yourself (efi (if needed), swap, /, /home (if wanted seperate)). Please tell me if you need assistance with this.

Comment: Thanks! 

I want to install only Ubuntu on that disk, so do I need partitions?

Comment: It is recommended to have a swap partition, in case you run out of RAM. If you have no other drives connected, you can use one of the default options instead of "something else", and it will create the proper partitions for you.